# How to add Angularfire2 to my Angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to add the Angularfire2 to a brand new Angular project. I was following the instructions in the official site

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md

When I ran into an error when I did the step 7 - Inject AngularFirestore, and these errors appear in the console:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Forgot to specify the version of Angular and my system
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 9.8.0
OS: win 10 x64
Angular: 5.2.10

Comment: can you create an stackblitz reproducing this problem?

Comment: for some reason, I created the stackblitz but could not reproduce the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" using AngularFirestore and firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374194/error-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-using-angularfirestore-and-fire)

Answer (score 1):

Angularfire maintainer here, you're going to want to upgrade rxjs to version 6 be compatible with AngularFire. We've upgraded to stay up to date with Angular 6.

```
npm i --save rxjs@^6.0
```

You should consider upgrading to Angular 6 yourself too, so things will be more compatible. If you can't to that at the moment or you have other dependencies on rxjs 5, install rxjs-compat too.

```
npm i --save rxjs-compat
```

Answer (score 0):

After some researching, try and error, I found the solution installing these versions:

```
npm uninstall angularfire2
npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3 --save
npm uninstall firebase
npm install firebase@4.8.0 --save
```