# "ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" using AngularFirestore and firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I want to use firebase and angularfire2 in my app, first of all, I installed them, and for the declarations:

in environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    firebase: {
    apiKey: 'sfsdfdsff',
    authDomain: 'sfsdfdf',
    databaseURL: 'https://ng-sfsdfsf.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'ng-fitnesssfsdfdsf',
    storageBucket: 'ng-fsdfsdfsfdecff5.appspot.com',
   messagingSenderId: '21331323'
   }
  };
```

in app.module.ts, imports:

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
AngularFirestoreModule
```

in the component where  want to get my data:

```
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
```

until this moment I have not an error, but when I want to declare my variable in the constructor to use it:

```
constructor(private trainingService: TrainingService, private 
db:AngularFirestore) { }
```

I have an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at eval (firestore.js:28)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
at Zone.run (zone.js:138)
```

In my package.json:

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.8.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"firebase": "^5.0.2",
```

and I don't know why?

thanks for your help

Comment: did u find any solution? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had same problem but i solved it. You can follow my work. This is a example for ionic.

Install rxjs

```
npm i rxjs@^6.0 rxjs-compat
```

import rxjs-compact to file

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs-compat';
import { map } from 'rxjs-compat/operators';
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50447449/6567753

Answer (score 38):

AngularFire maintainer here, we've had a number of breaking changes as we march towards 5.0 GA. In order to support Angular 6, recent releases of AngularFire require rxjs 6. While yes downgrading or pinning to an old version would work for quick and dirty fix, I wouldn't suggest that as it will leave you out of improvements to the libraries in the future.

I'd recommend upgrading rxj6 to version 6 and including `rxjs-compat` if you have dependencies that haven't yet upgraded:

`npm i rxjs@^6.0 rxjs-compat`

Keep an eye on the [angularfire changelog](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/releases) for important information on any breaking changes; once we hit GA we will abide by semver.

And for reference here's the [RXJS 5 => 6 migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md).

Comment: this is what I was looking from the angularfire forum since last two days. Finally it's worked!

Comment: Since this is a correct solution, why isn't this answer selected as the correct one?

Comment: because  sometimes upgrading to angular 6 is not an option at all ( ionic 3 & other angular5 dependencies). there should never be "breaking" changes on a production library, a separate branch should have been created, James.

Comment: Never? We had to change to support RXJS and Angular, which had breaking  changes. I mean feel free to fork all of those libs, it's open source after all.

Comment: what about angular 7

Answer (score 12):

```
npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6
```

This solved the issue

Answer (score 6):

I have the same error when installing `"angularfire2": 5.0.0-rc.9`.

The error is gone when I rollback to `5.0.0-rc.6`.

```
npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.6
npm install firebase@4.12.1
```

Comment: how did u do it. rollback?

Comment: @Sodhisaab uninstalled rc9 and `npm install angularfire2@^5.0.0-rc.6` and make sure it is compatible with firebase 4.12.1

Comment: I have already tried the command you said. but it installed ..rc.9 not 6.

Comment: Yes. This fix will work as @James Daniels said. But typically it should not be the case. When there is no chance of achieving then this is fine.

Comment: That worked, but this was super frustrating. Thank you for the help haifzhan.

Comment: As indicated by James Daniels this is not the solution and should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: @DavidWalschots I agree with that, the answer provided by maintainer is the best, my answer was an alternative for not breaking project

Answer (score 2):

This was my solution:

```
npm uninstall angularfire2
npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.4
npm uninstall firebase
npm install firebase@4.8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `^` this one in front of the version. 
So like this.

```js
{
    ...

    "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.6",
    "firebase": "4.12.1",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. As soon as i updated rxjs with `sudo npm update rxjs`. And then updated rxjs-compat with `sudo npm i rxjs@latest rxjs-compat`. After fixing the vulnerabilities and then running `ng build` then `ng serve`. This fixed my error. (on macOS)

Answer (score -1):

I first uninstalled firebase and angularfire2 with:

- `npm uninstall firebase`
- `npm uninstall angularfire2`

And then reinstalled again with:

- `npm install firebase@4.12.1`
- `npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.6`

Using `^` in the versions actually installed angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.9 so I just removed that part.