# Angular 5 firebase not working

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, zone.js

I updated my computer to High Sierra (clean install), after reinstall the angular-cli, and clone one of my previous project that uses Firebase and angularfirebase2 any operation of get data from firebase is not working. I got the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (changes.js:7)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (switchMap.js:91)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
    at RefCountSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:131)
    at RefCountSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
    at Subject.next (Subject.js:56)
    at ConnectableSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:131)
    at ConnectableSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
    at Notification.observe (Notification.js:32)
    at AsyncAction.DelaySubscriber.dispatch (delay.js:91)
```

Does anyone knows what is happening? 
The project is on angular 5

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" using AngularFirestore and firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374194/error-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-using-angularfirestore-and-fire)

Answer (score 1):

AngularFire maintainer here. You'll want to upgrade to rxjs 6, we've moved over to support Angular 6. Since you're using Angular 5 install the rxjs-compat lib to smooth over the changes until you migrate.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with firebase and angularfire.

I solved it with the following commands.

```
npm uninstall angularfire2
npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.3 --save
npm uninstall firebase
npm install firebase@4.8.0 --save
```

Comment: pinning to an already six month old version of the library is not a good solution, please just upgrade your dependencies