# Object(...) is not a function in ionic3 using angularfire2

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, angularfire2

I am trying to figure this error.

> "Object(...) is not a function"

I can't find it out what's wrong, I tried to delete my node_modules folder and started a new project, but it didn't fixed.

Here is my home.ts code :

```
shoppingList: Observable<Item[]>;
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private shopping: ShoppingListService) {
 this.shoppingList = this.shopping
 .getShoppingList()
 .snapshotChanges()
 .map(
 changes => {
 return changes.map(c => ({
 key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
 }))
 })
 }
```

Once i deleted these line :

```
this.shoppingList = this.shopping
 .getShoppingList()
 .snapshotChanges()
 .map(
 changes => {
 return changes.map(c => ({
 key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
 }))
 })
```

My apps work fine, is there something wrong with my code?

Here is my home.html code :

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-navbar color="primary">
 <ion-title>Sellmore Online Store</ion-title>
 <ion-buttons end>
 <button navPush="AddShoppingItemPage" ion-button>
 <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
 </button>
 </ion-buttons>
 </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
 <h2>Welcome to my apps!</h2>
 <ion-list>
 <ion-list-header>
 Items
 </ion-list-header>
 <ion-item *ngFor="let item of shoppingList | async" detail-push navPush="EditShoppingItemPage" [navParams]="{item: item}">
 {‌{item.name}}
 </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

is there something to do with that three dots? "..."

Here is my package.json

```
"@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
 "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
 "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
 "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
 "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
 "@angular/http": "5.2.10",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
 "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.7.0",
 "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
 "@ionic-native/crop": "^4.7.0",
 "@ionic-native/file": "^4.7.0",
 "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^4.7.0",
 "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
 "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.7.0",
 "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
 "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.9",
```

This error only happened when I want to get the data, my insert data to firebase its is okay, I can do insert function.

here is my service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ShoppingListService {

    private shoppingListRef = this.db.list<Item>('shopping-list');

    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {

    }

    getShoppingList() {
        return this.shoppingListRef;
    }

    addItem(item: Item) {
        return this.shoppingListRef.push(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you add `this.shopping
 .getShoppingList()` function to the question?

Comment: @SurajRao sure updated in my question sir

Comment: No need to call me sir :) I am not Knighted.. Also I dont see an issue with your code. But check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374194/error-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-using-angularfirestore-and-fire especially https://stackoverflow.com/a/50401572/4826457 answer

Comment: @SurajRao lol u are white knight for me, thanksss i downgrade the version of angularfire2 and firebase and it worked!! u can add it to answer, i will accept it sir, thank u

Comment: Its a duplicate of that question... there is no need for a repeat answer. Consider upvoting the answer which helped you

Comment: done, thank you @SurajRao