# Runtime Error = object is not a function

Tags: html, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm developing my first aplication with Ionic, and would like to display the firebase data at home.html, but when I start the serve show me this message in browser:

```
object(...) is not a function
```

I create this code at home.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular'; 
import { ShoppingListService } from '../../services/shopping-list/shopping-list.service';
import { AjaxObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/AjaxObservable';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Item } from '../../models/item/item.model';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
   selector: 'page-home',
   templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage { 

  shoppingList$ : Observable <Item[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private shopping:ShoppingListService) {
this.shoppingList$ = this.shopping
.getShoppingList() //pega a lista do banco de dados
.snapshotChanges() //chave e valor das infos do bd
.map(changes => {
    return changes.map(c => ({
      key: c.payload.key, 
      ...c.payload.val(),
    }));
  });
}



}
```

After this, I create the home.html:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>
  Items
</ion-list-header>
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of shoppingList$ | async">
  {{item.nomecontratante}}

</ion-item>
</ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Thanks for help me!

Comment: There is no `object` in the code you've posted. Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the issue. Currently you're the only person who can debug the error and track it to the line where it appears.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" using AngularFirestore and firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374194/error-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-using-angularfirestore-and-fire)

Comment: Are you sure that `c.payload.val` is a function and not an Object (holding data or maybe even holding a function)