# Issue when retrieving data from Firebase using ionic+angularfire2

Tags: ionic-framework, angularfire2

I am following a tutorial to create a Chat application using Ionic and AngularFire2.

However, I am having this error when I am trying to retrieve data from Firebase Database.

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at SwitchMapSubscriber.project (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:74005:76)
at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:62295:27)
at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20750:18)
at RefCountSubscriber.Subscriber._next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20786:26)
at RefCountSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20750:18)
at Subject.next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:23237:25)
at ConnectableSubscriber.Subscriber._next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20786:26)
at ConnectableSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20750:18)
at Notification.observe (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:51893:50)
at AsyncAction.DelaySubscriber.dispatch (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:76316:40)
```

My Chat.TS code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

/**
 * Generated class for the ChatPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-chat',
  templateUrl: 'chat.html',
})
export class ChatPage {

  username: string = '';
  message : string = '';
  //messages : object[] = [];
  items: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase , public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    console.log(this.navParams);
    this.username = this.navParams.get('username');
    this.items = db.list('chat').valueChanges();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ChatPage');
  }

  sendMessage(){
    this.db.list('/chat').push({
      username:this.username,
      message:this.message
    });
  }
}
```

My Chat.HTML code

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Chat</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>



<ion-content padding>

  <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
        {{ item | json }}
     </li>
   </ul>

</ion-content>


<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="message"></ion-input>
    <button ion-button icon-only (click)="sendMessage()"><ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

I had tried many different ways of doing it and I still get the same object error.
Anyone have any idea what is causing this error?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: angularfire2 version?

Comment: angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.10

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" using AngularFirestore and firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374194/error-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-using-angularfirestore-and-fire)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50401572/4826457 answer