# AngularFire error only when ng serve --prod

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I have an Angular 8 app, using npm package Angular Firebase (`https://github.com/angular/angularfire2`) and when I build the app with the Angular CLI command `ng build --prod` and deploy to my hosting I get the following Chrome Browser Console error:

```
TypeError: Object(...)(...).auth is not a function
```

If I instead build with the command `ng build --prod --optimization=false` the error does not occur.

Something with Angular CLI ng build option `optimization` set to true is causing the AngularFire2 npm package error.

I am not sure how to debug this issue further. Here is my package.json file:

```
    {
  "name": "bigmoenyshot",
  "version": "8.0.0",
  "license": "https://themeforest.net/licenses/terms/regular",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "serve": "ng serve",
    "serveProd": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --prod --optimization=true",
    "build": "ng build --prod=true --aot=true --extractCss=true --optimization=true",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "deploy": "ng build --prod=true --aot=true --extractCss=true --optimization=false && firebase deploy"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "8.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "8.0.0-beta.26",
    "@angular/forms": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "8.0.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "8.0.0",
    "@ngu/carousel": "1.5.4",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "10.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "3.0.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "15.0.2",
    "angular-calendar": "0.26.4",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.8.0",
    "angular-star-rating": "4.0.0-beta.3",
    "chart.js": "2.5.0",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "css-star-rating": "1.2.4",
    "date-fns": "1.28.5",
    "echarts": "4.2.1",
    "firebase": "^6.2.4",
    "flag-icon-css": "3.3.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "highlight.js": "9.15.6",
    "hopscotch": "0.3.1",
    "install": "0.12.2",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "ng2-charts": "2.2.2",
    "ng2-dragula": "2.1.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.3.0",
    "ng2-validation": "4.2.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "7.5.0",
    "ngx-echarts": "4.1.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "3.2.1",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-quill": "4.8.0",
    "npm": "6.9.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.4.0",
    "quill": "1.3.6",
    "rxjs": "6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.1.0",
    "web-animations-js": "github:angular/web-animations-js#release_pr208",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.6",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "7.3.8",
    "@angular/cli": "8.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.0.0",
    "@types/hopscotch": "0.2.30",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.3.0",
    "enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "2.0.0",
    "tslint": "4.5.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.5"
  }
}
```

And here is where I import the AngularFire2 Lib:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { User, auth } from 'firebase/app';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  user: Observable<User>

  constructor(
    private firBase: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router // Inject Firebase auth service
  ) {
    this.user = this.firBase.authState;
  }

  isLoggedIn(redirectUrl: string, isLoggedInRedirect?: string): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log('AuthService.isLoggedIn'); return this.user.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(authState => !!authState),
      tap(authenticated => {
        if (!authenticated) {
          console.log('user not authenticated');
          this.router.navigate([redirectUrl]);
          return;
        }
        console.log('user Authenticated');
        if (isLoggedInRedirect) {
          this.router.navigate([isLoggedInRedirect]);
        }
      })
    );
  }

  getDisplayName(): string {
    return this.firBase.auth.currentUser.displayName;
  }

  // Sign up with email/password
  async signUp(email: string, password: string) {
    try {
      const result = await this.firBase.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      console.log("successfully registered!");
      console.log(result.user);
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  }

  // Sign in with email/password
  async signIn(email: string, password: string, rememberMe: boolean): Promise<string> {
    let session = 'session'; //only persist in the current session or tab, and will be cleared when the tab or window in which the user authenticated is closed

    if (rememberMe) {
      session = 'local'; //state will be persisted even when the browser window is closed or the activity
    }

    console.log('persistence type', session);
    try {
      const _ = await this.firBase.auth.setPersistence(session);
      const result = await this.firBase.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      console.log('signin success');
      return 'success';
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
      return error.message;
    }
  }

  async signOut() {
    try {
      const _ = await this.firBase.auth.signOut();
      this.user = this.firBase.authState;
      console.log('signOut complete, currentUser', this.firBase.auth.currentUser);
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  }

  async forgotPassword(email: string): Promise<string> {
    try {
      await this.firBase.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
      return 'Reset Email Sent';
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
      return error.message;
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my app.module:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { GestureConfig } from '@angular/material';
import {
  PerfectScrollbarModule,
  PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG,
  PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface
} from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';


import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService } from './shared/inmemory-db/inmemory-db.service';

import { rootRouterConfig } from './app.routing';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { ErrorHandlerService } from './shared/services/error-handler.service';
import { SessionsModule } from './views/sessions/sessions.module';

import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
//import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { StartComponent } from './start.component';

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient);
}

const DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG: PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface = {
  suppressScrollX: true
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SessionsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SharedModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    //AngularFirestoreModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    PerfectScrollbarModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, { passThruUnknownUrl: true }),
    RouterModule.forRoot(rootRouterConfig, { useHash: true, enableTracing: false })
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, StartComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorHandlerService },
    { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: GestureConfig },
    { provide: PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG, useValue: DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You already set this `--optimization=true` in your JSON file. Do you want to change it to `false` or is it required for you?

Comment: @UtkarshDubey my goal is Angular CLI build default value optimization=true, app only works if optimization=false currently

Comment: Try this `firebase.default.auth`. Reference: [firebase auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48592656/firebase-auth-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @UtkarshDubey I have that is for ReactJs and vanilla Javascript. This is Typescript

Comment: Wherever you find this line `this.firBase.auth.`, can you please replace it with this line `this.firBase.default.auth.`.

Comment: @UtkarshDubey incorrect, that would work with Javascript, this app is written in Typescript this.fireBase.default = null

Comment: Do you have this package [@angular-devkit/build-optimize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer)

Comment: @UtkarshDubey No I do not...

Comment: Please! install.

Comment: @UtkarshDubey "Update 2017-11-06: Since Angular CLI 1.5, the Build Optimizer is on by default when doing a production build." https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2017/07/26/shrinking-angular-bundles-with-the-angular-build-optimizer.aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196405/discussion-between-utkarsh-dubey-and-brian-ogden).

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue with AngularFireFunctions. Managed to solve it by adding AngularFireFunctionsModule to my app.module.ts. Just turn on sourceMaps for your prod build, so you can debug which library is actually broken. Turns out that without the module everything will work fine in development, but when you build with --prod flag optimizer removes parts of the code it shouldn't and there are loose ends left.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the complete answer, it just my research. Which I'm putting here, hope it helps someone.

**Check this command**

```
node --max-old-space-size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot=false --optimization=true --sourceMap=false --buildOptimizer=false
```

> Comment: Can you please! remove AOT flag or make it false?
>
> Reference:
>   https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14666#issuecomment-507057022

---

**buildOptimizer is not working anymore**

```
--buildOptimizer=false
```

> Reference:
>   https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10658#issuecomment-387296781
>
> Reference:
>   https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10655#issuecomment-449319049

---

- `--source-map` generate 10% smaller app

> Reference:
>   https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11129#issuecomment-396274621

---

- set target to `es5`, build target `es2015` have these issues

> Reference:
>   https://github.com/datorama/akita/issues/179#issuecomment-472505123
>
> Reference:
>   https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7799#issuecomment-387167797

Answer (score 0):

> according to @jamesdaniels answer [this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1668#issuecomment-390089718)

```
npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save
```

It solved the issue.

and this is Your Solution [Credit @Biswajit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374194/error-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-using-angularfirestore-and-fire)

Comment: Already have that package installed, see my package.json file included in my question

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by importing the firebase dependencies I was using on the component with error, you can do something like that:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/storage';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afFirestore: AngularFirestore,
    private afStorage: AngularFireStorage
  ) {
    try {
      firebase.app();
    } catch (err) {
      firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig);
    }
}
```

Dont forget to place your firebase configs at your environment file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Going back to

```
"@angular/fire": "~5.1.0",
```

solved the problem, although there're some warnings about version incompatibilities with other packages (no compilation or runtime errors).

Answer (score 0):

In My case, having the AngularFireAuthModule, and AngularFirestoreModule in app.module.ts worked since I was using both of those in my app.

```
imports: [
    ...
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    ...],
```