# ERROR TypeError: "ot(...).auth is not a function"

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm deploying my angular application which uses firebase services. 
My code works on `development` mode which is serve through @angular-cli `ng serve`. However, there's some weird error after building the source code and hosting it using `live-server`.

```
import { Router } from  "@angular/router";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from  "@angular/fire/auth";
import { User } from  'firebase';
import { auth } from  'firebase/app';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  public user:  User;
  constructor(public  afAuth:  AngularFireAuth, public  router:  Router ) { 
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.user = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', null);
      }
    })
  }

  get isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    const  user  =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    return  user  !==  null;
  }

  authState() {
    return this.afAuth.authState
  }

  login() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

  logout() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    this.router.navigate(['']);
  }

}
```

**Result in browser console.**
`ERROR TypeError: "ot(...).auth is not a function"`

Comment: Which line are you getting this error?

Comment: I'm not sure which line is causing the error because this error does not appear when i try to run it via angular cli but after ng build --prod and run through lite-server it gives me an error auth is not a function". I can't debug the result because it's from builld files.

Comment: have you installed all the firebase modules?If so try deleting the node_modules and installing again.

Comment: yes i did but it still failing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48592656/firebase-auth-is-not-a-function

Comment: i think the issue is similar to this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56962202/angularfire-error-only-when-ng-serve-prod