# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: xp(...).functions is not a function TypeError: xp(...).functions is not a function

Tags: angular, angularfire

I am deploying an `Angular(8.0.0)` project and got such an error when visiting the deployed website. This is not the first time deploying the project but it's the first time to get such an error and I searched online but have no clue what this is about. I am using ***Firebase*** hosting the project.

There's no Error/Warning when I test it on my laptop everything works properly.

> main-es2015.936cb835ea7348311cbf.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: xp(...).functions is not a function
> TypeError: xp(...).functions is not a function
> at main-es2015.936cb835ea7348311cbf.js:1
> at a.invoke (polyfills-es2015.5728f680576ca47e99fe.js:1)
> at t.run (polyfills-es2015.5728f680576ca47e99fe.js:1)
> at Gi.runOutsideAngular (main-es2015.936cb835ea7348311cbf.js:1)
> at new  (main-es2015.936cb835ea7348311cbf.js:1)
> at main-es2015.936cb835ea7348311cbf.js:1
> at Ir (main-es2015.936cb835ea7348311cbf.js:1)
> at Tr (main-es2015.936cb835ea7348311cbf.js:1)
> at main-es2015.936cb835ea7348311cbf.js:1
> at Ir (main-es2015.936cb835ea7348311cbf.js:1)
> at P (polyfills-es2015.5728f680576ca47e99fe.js:1)
> at P (polyfills-es2015.5728f680576ca47e99fe.js:1)
> at polyfills-es2015.5728f680576ca47e99fe.js:1
> at a.invokeTask (polyfills-es2015.5728f680576ca47e99fe.js:1)
> at Object.onInvokeTask (main-es2015.936cb835ea7348311cbf.js:1)
> at a.invokeTask (polyfills-es2015.5728f680576ca47e99fe.js:1)
> at t.runTask (polyfills-es2015.5728f680576ca47e99fe.js:1)
> at _ (polyfills-es2015.5728f680576ca47e99fe.js:1)

Has anyone encountered this before?

Dependencies I have:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.0",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.4.0",
    "firebase": "^6.3.5",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
```

I didn't change/update any existing dependencies, the change for the project is adding one cloud function which works fine when test with 'ng serve'

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374194/error-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-using-angularfirestore-and-fire

Comment: @PatrikAlexits Thanks for your comment! It shouldn't be my case as no dependencies upgraded...

Comment: did you introduce a new import? some module not correctly imported maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Import the functions

```
import 'firebase/functions'
```

Or this, if up to date version:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import 'firebase-functions';
admin.initializeApp();
```